# How to grant select privileges on a whole database? (not a schema)

Tags: postgresql, privileges

postgres separates schema and database concepts.
How do I grant select privileges to a user on all tables in a db?

```
postgres=# GRANT ALL on DATABASE dbname to tbdev;
GRANT
```

great, all permissions ya'd think? Except actually no, those don't include any DB operations like `SELECT`. Then tried:

```
postgres=# GRANT SELECT on DATABASE dbname to tbdev;
ERROR:  invalid privilege type SELECT for database
```

Reading up SELECT is not for databases but pgs abstraction layer of schemas. So tried using the public schema but none of these work:

```
GRANT ALL on SCHEMA public to tbdev;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO tbdev ;
```

as that user I still get:

```
ticket_battle=> select * from events;
ERROR:  permission denied for table events
```

So how does one normally create a user and a DB with PG?

Comment: fair enough; as mentioned I did use `ALTER ROLE` and `CREATEDB` privilege. that said, original question of how do i create a db and access it... what obvious step did i do wrong here? does the rest seem like the normal steps you take?

Comment: actually i'm gonna remove those points as that distracts from the main question.

Answer (score 0):

You may have found out (as I did) that SELECT, like many table-level operations, can only be granted on TABLE.

It appears that we can't grant on all tables in a database, but we can do it on all tables in a schema, which there may be more than one in a database.

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO your_username;
```